# How to see view in SQL After create view in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: sql, microsoft-dynamics

How to see view in SQL After create view in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009.
Please I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply do the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Your View Name Here]
```